# How to reset table cells to prototype?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have button on every row and I want to show UIActivityIndicatorView in place of the button which I press to show loading process. So I've done it by changing button properties to make it look like a spinner like this:

```
[search_btn_outlet setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[spinner startAnimating];
spinner.frame = search_btn_outlet.bounds;
[search_btn_outlet addSubview:spinner];
search_btn_outlet.enabled = NO;
```

Now I want to reload my table with new data. But method [tableview reloadData] calls same cellForRowAtIndexPath that reuses previous spoiled cells. I can put there code like this:

```
[boy.search_btn_outlet setTitle:@"Button name" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
boy.search_btn_outlet.enabled = YES;
```

**But I wonder if I can reset my table at once to what was assigned in storyboard cell prototype? And if I can't, how to deal with that spinner, that I've added when button was pressed?**

**Edit:** I was confused because I come from Android and there in the same situation cells return to default prototype after they disappeared. Apparently in iOS developer is responsible for this with prepareForReuse. (Thx Abizern).

What I am doing is holding pointer to row button and row state “isLoading” inside my row object. In cellForTowAtIndexPath I either setting button to normal or to loading animation. To remove spinner I am also holding it's reference.

Other way to do it is to alter row views only if isLoading is true. And my refresh button when pressed will loop for all the row items in the array and return their views to normal.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"boy_cell";       
    BoyItem *boy = [self.boys_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];           
    BoyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];           
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[BoyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }       
        cell.delegate = self;   //for search button callback
        cell.cellIndex = indexPath.row;           
        /* save pointer to the button to change it when button is pressed */
        boy.search_btn_outlet = cell.search_btn_outlet;               
        if(boy.isLoading){
            [self setRowLoading:boy];
        }
        else{
            [self setRowNormal:boy];
        }            
        [cell.name_lbl setText:boy.name];
        [cell.time_lbl setText:boy.time];
    }       
    return cell;
}

-(void)setRowLoading:(BoyItem*)boy{
    [boy.search_btn_outlet setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [spinner setColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    spinner.frame = boy.search_btn_outlet.bounds;
    boy.spinner = spinner;
    [boy.search_btn_outlet addSubview:spinner];
    boy.search_btn_outlet.enabled = NO;
}

-(void)setRowNormal:(BoyItem*)boy{
    [boy.search_btn_outlet setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    boy.search_btn_outlet.enabled = YES;
    [boy.spinner removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)didClickOnCellAtIndex:(NSInteger)cellIndex withData:(id)data
{
    BoyItem *boy = [self.boys_array objectAtIndex:cellIndex];
    if(boy!=nil){
        boy.isLoading = true;
        [self setRowLoading:boy];
    }
}
```

I am not 100% sure it is a proper way. But if it's close, I hope it helps someone.

**Edit2**: And then I discovered that there are at least two more ways to refresh cells properties besides reloading whole table. It gives a benefit of animation when you change cell height.
One way is to put your changes inside or before those methods:

```
            [tableview beginUpdates];
            //boy_cell.backgroundColor =row_color;
            [tableview endUpdates];
```

It calls heightForRowAtIndexPath for every row so you want to put new height into object belonging to every cell. Be aware that you need to check if this row is visible. Otherwise you may change colour of the row, which has been reused for other cell of your table.

Also you can reload specific row of the table. cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called for one row:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
[tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: You reset the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that `prepareForReuse` is for.